# currency number format using spreadsheet gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, spreadsheet

I 'm using Spreadsheet gem to create excel sheet. 
how can I apply 'currency' number format to a particular cell ?

Answer (score 6):

Not tried it out but perhaps the following will point you in the right direction:

```
nb_format = Spreadsheet::Format.new  :number_format => '$#,###.##'
cell.set_format(0, nb_format)
```

Comment: currency_format = Spreadsheet::Format.new :number_format => '$#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)'
sheet.row(index).set_format(5, currency_format)

This worked better for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use one of Excel's built in currency formats, one hack is to *use Excel* to format a spreadsheet cell (say Row 1, Col A) with the format you want.  Save it, then use the [spreadsheet gem](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet) to [read the format](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/blob/master/GUIDE.md#reading-is-easy) Excel gave that cell.  In my case, I got `_([$$-409]* #,##0.00_);_([$$-409]* \\(#,##0.00\\);_([$$-409]* \"-\"??_);_(@_)` as the format for USD.  Then you can use it like so:

```
currency_format = Spreadsheet::Format.new number_format: "_([$$-409]* #,##0.00_);_([$$-409]* \\(#,##0.00\\);_([$$-409]* \"-\"??_);_(@_)"
sheet.row(r).set_format(col, currency_format)
```