# With Ruby Spreadsheet gem, can I format a cell as currency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, export, spreadsheet, xls

The relevant code within the action is below:

```
# XLS
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
sheet1 = book.create_worksheet
currency_format = Spreadsheet::Format.new :number_format => '0.00'

sheet1.row(0).concat 'Example header', 'Example header 2', 'Example header 3'



    @transactions.each_with_index do |tx, index|

      row = sheet1.row(index + 1)
      row.push tx.attr1, tx.attr2, tx.attr3      
      row.set_format(1, currency_format)
      row.set_format(2, currency_format)

    end


data = StringIO.new '';
book.write data


respond_to do |format|
  format.xls { send_data data.string, :disposition => "attachment; filename=transactions.xls" }
end
```

It exports okay, and I can format the cells as numbers, but Excel (on the Mac) is not allowing me to total up the values in the number formatted column. Can I choose *currency* format?

Thanks

Comment: I've never heard of Excel "not allowing" you to total values. Isn't that its basic purpose?

Answer (score 3):

Use `'$#,###.##'` as the number format. See [currency number format using spreadsheet gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973297/currency-number-format-using-spreadsheet-gem) for more info.

Comment: A useful thing i noticed looking into this is that if you're using Open Office Calc (and it might to do this in excel too), if you change a cell's format in the menu, there's a text field which shows the "format code".  You can paste this into your application as the value of the `:number_format` option